# How to pull consecutive months data in sql server even if there is null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm newbie trying to create a SQL query to find how much each Theater has sold the tickets per month during previous year (i.e. for all 12 months).  If the collection amount is null or blank I need to produce an output as Zero of any such given month in that year.

I have two tables as below mentioned:

**TABLE 1:**

```
Month_Number    Year
1                  2016
2                  2016
3                  2016
4                  2016
5                  2016
6                  2016
7                  2016
8                  2016
9                  2016
10                 2016
11                 2016
12                 2016
```

**TABLE 2:**

```
Theater    month    Amount_In_Thousands
ABC          1       165
ABC          3       70
ABC          4       102
GHI          1       45
GHI          2       70
GHI          3       42
GHI          4       57
ABC          6       122
ABC          7       67
ABC          8       22
ABC          9       80
ABC          11      46
ABC          12      38
```

You might have noticed for 'ABC' Theater there is 0 or null values for month 2, month 5 and month 10. I am unable to produce these missing months with zero value.  I tried with simple *left outer join* but still the data output row doesn't show with month/year and *zero* value.

I need to produce the output as below:

**OUTPUT**

```
Movie_Theators  Month   Amount_In_Thounds   
ABC                1    165 
ABC                2    0    *  
ABC                3    70  
ABC                4    102 
ABC                5    0    *  
ABC                6    122 
ABC                7    67  
ABC                8    22  
ABC                9    80  
ABC                10   0    *  
ABC                11   46  
ABC                12   38  
GHI                1    45  
GHI                2    70  
GHI                3    42  
GHI                4    57
```

Can anybody please help me how to write sql script in order to produce the output as shown above.  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Just use a `LEFT JOIN`, instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Post your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` between every theater and month-year, and then perform a `LEFT JOIN` with `Table2`:

```
SELECT  A.Theater,
        B.Month_Number,
        B.[Year],
        ISNULL(C.Amount_In_Thousands,0) Amount_In_Thousands
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT Theater
        FROM dbo.Table2) A -- or use a dbo.Theater table if you have one
CROSS JOIN dbo.Table1 B
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 C
    ON A.Theater = C.Theater
    AND B.Month_Number = C.[month]
    AND B.[Year] = C.[Year];
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent and precise.  Thank you so much for quick help.  I choose your answer best.